# rendering html templates through mails sent through django

Tags: django, templates

I have a django template which I have to send as email body, the variables that i am sending are getting rendered in the email accordingly but the html tags used in the template are not rendering.Here is the code..

```
t = loader.get_template('registration/subscription_employee.html')
                c = {'site_name': current_site.domain,'user': user,'employer':employer}
                send_mail(("Subscription Agreement of %s")%data['username'], t.render(Context(c)), None, [settings.PAYPAL_PRIMARY_EMAIL,data['email']],fail_silently = True)
```

how can i ensure that html tags are also rendered accordingly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You either need to use attach_alternative() or specify a content sub type for your message. See the docs on sending HTML emails: http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.3/topics/email/. The HTML-specific info is about halfway down the page. Hope that helps you out.

Answer (score 3):

By default, django sends text/plain emails, so you won't see any HTML in your letters.

You can change this, take a look at the [documentation](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/email/?from=olddocs#sending-alternative-content-types)

```
from django.core.mail import EmailMultiAlternatives

subject, from_email, to = 'hello', 'from@example.com', 'to@example.com'
text_content = 'This is an important message.'
html_content = '<p>This is an <strong>important</strong> message.</p>'
msg = EmailMultiAlternatives(subject, text_content, from_email, [to])
msg.attach_alternative(html_content, "text/html")
msg.send()
```

Answer (score 1):

You're sending HTML message as plain text email. If you want to send HTML only, use [**EmailMessage**](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/email/#emailmessage-objects) and set add header `{'Content-type': 'text/html'}`. Much user friendlier solution would be to send both text and HTML with [**EmailMultiAlternatives**](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/email/#sending-alternative-content-types).